# Cannot dump fixtures for django.contrib.auth. Why does `python manage.py dumpdata auth` return an empty list?

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

The problem:

```
$ python manage.py dumpdata auth.user
[]
```

But I do have users:

```
$ python manage.py shell
Python 3.6.8 (default, Dec 24 2018, 19:24:27)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.all().count()
3
```

And `loaddata` works fine:

```
$ cat user.json
[
    {
        "model": "auth.user",
        "fields": {
            "username": "fixture_user"
        }
    }
]

$ python manage.py loaddata user.json
Installed 1 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

My Django version:

```
$ pip show Django
Name: Django
Version: 1.11.7
```

My database is a local PostgreSQL database.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: what does `python manage.py dumpdata auth` give ?

Comment: Also nothing: `$ python manage.py dumpdata auth`
`[]`